# Using delegate and inheritance to define which method is run inside the child class

Tags: c#

I have a child and a parent class in C#. I want to point the Calc delegate to one of several methods. this is determined each time the Reset() method is called.
Below is a working example. 
However, I want this functionality of pointing the delegate to reside on the Parent class. Since the parent does not contain the methods, I don't know how to do it...

```
    class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Model Model = new Model();
        Model.Env1 = true;
        Child Ch = new Child(Model);
        Ch.Reset();
        Ch.Calc(); Ch.Calc(); Ch.Calc();
        Console.WriteLine();
        Model.Env1 = false;
        Ch.Reset();
        Ch.Calc(); Ch.Calc(); Ch.Calc();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public class Parent
{
    public Model Model { get; set; }
    public Parent(Model model)
    {
        Model = model;
    }
    public delegate void StateHandler();
    public StateHandler Calc;
}
public class Model
{
    public bool Env1 { get; set; }
}
public class Child : Parent, IChild
{
    public Child (Model model)
        : base (model)
    {
    }
    public void Reset()
    {
        if (Model.Env1)
            Calc = CalcHeavy;
        else
            Calc = CalcLight;
    }
    public void CalcHeavy()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("CalcHeavy is active");
    }
    public void CalcLight()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("CalcLight is active");
    }
}
public interface IChild
{
    void CalcHeavy();
    void CalcLight();
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to do that?  The child class is responsible for knowing about its methods, and, therefore, which of its methods is the appropriate choice for assignment to `Calc`.

Comment: @phoog, see my answer for why. Wanting to control the selection of a method in one class, yet define the methods in another is an example of separation of concerns.

Comment: @DavidArno but your answer is subtly different from the sample code.  I will add comment to your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While trying to get the answer I liked to work, I managed to solve it in a different way by making the Parent abstract, and it works.

```
    class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Model Model = new Model();
        Model.Env1 = true;
        Child Ch = new Child(Model);

        Ch.Calc(); Ch.Calc(); Ch.Calc();
        Console.WriteLine();
        Model.Env1 = false;

        Ch = new Child(Model);
        Ch.Calc(); Ch.Calc(); Ch.Calc();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public abstract class Parent
{
    public Model Model { get; set; }
    public Parent(Model model)
    {
        Model = model;
        if (Model.Env1)
            Calc = CalcHeavy;
        else
            Calc = CalcLight;
    }

    public Action Calc;

    public abstract void CalcHeavy();
    public abstract void CalcLight();

}
public class Model
{
    public bool Env1 { get; set; }
}
public class Child : Parent
{
    public Child(Model model) : base(model) { }

    public override void CalcHeavy()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("CalcHeavy is active");
    }
    public override void CalcLight()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("CalcLight is active");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do that would be to have the `Child` class inject its methods into the Parent at construction time. That way, the `Parent` class makes the choice, but the `Child` class defines the functionality:

```
public class Parent
{
    private readonly Action _env1Method;
    private readonly Action _notEnv1Method;
    private readonly Model _model;

    public Parent(Model model, 
                  Action env1Method, 
                  Action notEnv1Method)
    {
        _model = model;
        _env1Method = env1Method;
        _notEnv1Method = notEnv1Method;
        Reset();
    }

    public Action Calc { get; private set; }

    public void Reset()
    {
        Calc = _model.Env1 ? _env1Method : _notEnv1Method;
    }
}

public class Model
{
    public bool Env1 { get; set; }
}

public class Child : Parent
{
    public Child (Model model) : base (model, CalcHeavy, CalcLight) {}

    private static void CalcHeavy()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("CalcHeavy is active");
    }

    private static void CalcLight()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("CalcLight is active");
    }
}
```

Also, I'd get rid of `StateHandler` and just use `Action` instead. Don't create a new delegate when a standard one exists already.

Comment: I'm reading your answer great hopes (i think it can take my creativity options to a new level). However, the code does not compile (while mine does). 
I capitalized the Action in "public action Calc { get; private set; }"
but I still get Error: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, ....Child.CalcHeavy()'  
and the same with...CalcLight...

Comment: This is different, however: To let the parent class make the choice, you introduce a new requirement: that the child class supply two methods based on their applicability to the Env1 value.  True, this is separation of concerns, but it may not satisfy the requirement at hand.  For example, a different child class may need to extend the decision tree to three methods, selected based on the value of an integer rather than a boolean.

Comment: indeed the decision tree might expand to 3 or 4, but if this happens, it will be for a good reason, in which case all children will, and should be aligned. (that's why in my question I included an interface: I want to force the children to implement the Light and the Heavy). Therefore, David Arno's solution really suites my need like a glove. 
- just need to get it to compile...

Comment: @Guy, my apologies, I really should check code compiles before posting it here! There's a problem. I forgot the fact that one cannot reference fields and methods of the child class when calling `base()`. The only solution to that is to make the methods static. This will likely be a show-stopper for you.

Comment: indeed, I cannot make them static. Have a look at the proposed solution I just posted.

Comment: @Guy, I think your solution is likely the best one. We were possibly trying to be too clever by missing inheritance and delegates and a basic inheritance model looks a lot simpler (and have the advantage that it'll work! :)

Answer (score 0):

One way is to move the "Reset" method to the parent class and do something like this:

```
public void Reset()
{
       var child = this as IChild;

        if (child != null && Model.Env1)
            Calc = child.CalcHeavy;
        else
            Calc = child.CalcLight;
}
```

Comment: I cannot move the Reset as it's specific to each child.